# Unity Entity Framework within ASP.NET WebAPI 2

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I have a very weird problem with Unity here. I have the following:

```
public class UnityConfig
{

    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        container.RegisterType<IDBContext, MyDbContext>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IUserDbContext>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(c =>
        {
            var tenantConnectionString = c.Resolve<ITenantConnectionResolver>().ResolveConnectionString();
            return new UserDbContext(tenantConnectionString);
        }));
    }
}
```

and then in the WebApiConfig.cs file within the Reigster method:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();    
UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(container);
config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
```

Basically, what I want to happen in the above code is on every request to the API, I want Unity to new up a UserDbContext based on the user (multi-tenant kind of environment). Now the TenantConnectionResolver is responsible for figuring out the Connection String and then I use that connection string to new up UserDbContext.

Also note (not shown above) that TenantConnectionResolver takes an IDbConext in its constructor because I need it to figure out the connection string based on user information in that database.

But for some reason, the code within the InjectionFactory runs at random times. For example, I call //mysite.com/controller/action/1 repetitively from a browser, the code in the InjectionFactory will occasionally run but not on each request.

Am I incorrectly configuring Unity? Has anybody encountered anything similar to this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use [PerRequestLifetimeManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perrequestlifetimemanager(v=pandp.30).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very likely related to the `LifetimeManager` you are using. `PerThreadLifetimeManager` is not adapted in a web context, as threads are pooled and will serve multiple requests in sequence.

`PerRequestLifetimeManager` is probably what you want to use.

Comment: Thanks but i can't find the PerRequestLifetimeManager

Comment: It is in the package `Unity.Mvc`.

Comment: Seems like it has solved it. I'll give it a few more tests. Thanks to all for the help

Comment: `Unity.Mvc` pulls in a bunch of MVC dependencies (like Razor for example) that I do not want or need in my Web Api project.  How does one use `PerRequestLifetimeManager` in Web Api without pulling in these other assemblies?